# ansible connects with default remote_user even if I specify another one

Tags: ansible

I create a virtual linux server using an ansible module from my hoster. This works fine.
The next task should add a user 'ansible' using

```
- include: task-files/users_create_ansible_user.yml
    delegate_to: '{{ createdserver.ipv4_address }}'
    remote_user: root
```

As you see I added remote_user in here (I also added it to the task that is included).

But despite those two remote_user entries it still tries to connect with the remote_user that is set in ansible.cfg (There I set remote_user to 'ansible' as I want to do all the following tasks with this user once it has been created).

More Details:

This is the first task in the included tasks file (this fails)

```
- name: "Create 'ansible' user"
  remote_user: root
  user:
    name: "ansible"
```

that returns

```
fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ansible@116.203.119.43: Permission denied (publickey,password).", "unreachable": true}'
```

As you can see it does not connect with the specified remote_user: root but with the user 'ansible' (not created yet). When I change the remote_user in ansible.cfg to root...it can connect here.

Can anyone guide me to my misconception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: "*Does not connect with the specified `remote_user`: root but with the user ansible."*

A: Very probably the `remote_user` is overridden by the variable `ansible_user`. The variable has a higher [precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#precedence-categories). See the last section. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        ansible_user: admin
    - command: whoami
      remote_user: root
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

give

```yaml
    result.stdout: admin
```

This should work without the variable `ansible_user`. [remote_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#task) is defined on the task level. For example,

```yaml
    - command: whoami
      remote_user: admin
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout

    - command: whoami
      remote_user: root
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

give

```yaml
    result.stdout: admin

    result.stdout: root
```

---

**Debug**

Put a debug task into the code and see the value of the variable `ansible_user`. For example,

```yaml
- debug:
    var: ansible_user
- name: Create 'ansible' user
  remote_user: root
  user:
    name: ansible
```

---

**Use ansible_user**

If there shouldn't be any chance to override the value use `ansible_user`.

See also parameter [remote_user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/ssh.html#parameter-remote_user) of the SSH connect plugin. `remote_user` is the parameter in the Ansible configuration. Instead, it is also possible to use variable `ansible_user` to change the remote user from a playbook, or task. The variable has the highest [preference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#precedence-categories). See the last section. For example,

```yaml
    - command: whoami
      register: result
      vars:
        ansible_user: admin
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout

    - command: whoami
      register: result
      vars:
        ansible_user: root
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

work as expected and give

```yaml
    result.stdout: admin

    result.stdout: root
}
```

[Best practice](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/connection/ssh.html#synopsis) is to use `public key authentication` with the password of the private key provided by `ssh-agent`.

---

**Disable root login**

The best practice is to [Disable root login](https://linux-audit.com/audit-and-harden-your-ssh-configuration/#disable-root-login): *"Use a normal user account to initiate your connection instead, together with sudo."* For example,

```yaml
    - command: whoami
      register: result
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
      become_user: root
      vars:
        ansible_user: admin
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
    result.stdout: root
```

The remote user admin must be allowed `sudo`, of course

```bash
root@test_01> cat /usr/local/etc/sudoers
...
admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

---

**Precedence**

It's necessary to understand that many configuration parameters can be overridden by variables from the play to the task level. In most cases, these variables are created from the parameter's name by adding the prefix `ansible_`. The variable `ansible_user` and parameter `remote_user` are exceptions (FWIW, I'm not aware of any other exception).

It's also important to keep in mind that the [variables got precedence over the playbook's keywords](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#precedence-categories). As an example, the directives [become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/become.html#directives) can also be specified as variables. For example,

```yaml
    - command: whoami
      register: result
      vars:
        ansible_user: admin
        ansible_become: true
        ansible_become_method: sudo
        ansible_become_user: root
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
```

gives

```yaml
    result.stdout: root
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer! I will accept it as soon as it's possible. 
Maybe you want to have a look at a follow-up question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61864035/ansible-how-to-add-a-password-prompt-in-tasks-file