# How can I auth as different users without creating multiple hosts in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

Specifically, I want to run most actions on host `host` as my personal `chris` user, but some commands as `root`. I think `become: true` wouldn't work well because `chris` needs a password to become `root`, and I don't want to have to enter this every time I deploy. My local public key is allowed to log into `host` as either `chris` or `root` (I've put my public key in both `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `/home/chris/.ssh/authorized_keys`).

Is there a common way to tell ansible to perform some commands as another user by **ssh'ing as that user**, rather than by **becoming** that user via sudo? Or am I stuck creating two separate hosts in my hosts.yml, one with `ansible_user: chris` and one with `ansible_user: root`?

Comment: 1) `I think become: true wouldn't work well because chris needs a password to become root` <= you can easily add that password encrypted with `ansible-vault` to your inventory/playbook/tasks in the `ansible_become_password` variable. 2) `I've put my public key in both /root/.ssh/authorized_keys and /home/chris/.ssh/authorized_keys` <= this is an extremely bad practice, root login should be disabled allowing only given users to escalate privileges when needed.

Answer (score 1):

- *ansible_user* is a [connection variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#connection-variables). See [Controlling how Ansible behaves: precedence rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#controlling-how-ansible-behaves-precedence-rules) on how to declare or override the variable.
- See detail in [Ansible connects with default remote_user ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61834148/ansible-connects-with-default-remote-user-even-if-i-specify-another-one/61835991#61835991)
- Be aware that the best practice is to [Disable Root Logins](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#Disable_Root_Logins).